# Magento coupon code generate some % off for next order

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon, coupon-codes

I want to generate the coupon 30% off for next order. means suppose any customer already bought one product from our store than they get 30% off on next order.

How can I generate this coupon in Magento 1.9.1